# What are the generic-pae directories in /lib/modules?

Tags: ubuntu, kernel-modules, libraries

When listing the content of the dirctory `/lib/modules` I see a list of `generic-pae` directories (Ubuntu 12.04):

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Apr 23  2012 3.2.0-23-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 20  2012 3.2.0-27-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 20  2012 3.2.0-29-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 20  2012 3.2.0-30-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Nov 20  2012 3.2.0-31-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 16  2013 3.2.0-32-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 16  2013 3.2.0-33-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 16  2013 3.2.0-34-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 16  2013 3.2.0-35-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 16  2013 3.2.0-36-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 16  2013 3.2.0-37-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 16  2013 3.2.0-38-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 16  2013 3.2.0-39-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 May 16  2013 3.2.0-41-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Jun 18 08:26 3.2.0-48-generic-pae
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 4096 Oct  3 07:47 3.2.0-54-generic-pae
```

What are all of these directories? What is their content?

Can I remove the ones with a lower number, because they take up quite a lot of space?

Comment: As you already know from your tabs, they relate to kernel versions. Use the package manager to remove unneeded kernels. Though I only have the bigmem kernel installed and modules for 486, 686, pea, bigmem, amd64, so not sure why. Am looking into it.